Is there a convention of propeller tip separation from the wind tunnel walls?
Blockage ratio is commonly used to address the effect of confinement on the propeller's performance tested inside a closed test section of a wind tunnel. In most cases, blockage corrections (like Glauert's) are applied to the measured velocity, assuming that the propeller was positioned along the centerline of the test section.

What happens if the propeller model is offset from the center? Would these corrections be equally valid in that scenario?

Is there a convention on how close the propeller tip could be to the wall before the wall starts to affect the slipstream significantly? Would experiments be the only option to check this out?


Thanks!

For your particular propeller and test cell, the most trustworthy check would be to try different offsets from center, both vertically and horizontally if the cell's cross section isn't square, and from that derive a secondary correction (since you know the prop didn't change).
